# Python3 Matrix Sum Harvesting

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Hello i have created the code and i wonder if it is possible to sort the columns by sum, to be smaller and grow to the right

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(100, size=(4,4))
a = list(a)
print(a)
b = sum(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
    Matrix
    [[26 11 39 81]
    [55 82 20 81]
    [ 7 42 28 26]
    [69 50 24 86]]
   Secnd  THird  FRST  RD
    Sum
    [157 185 111 274]
   Secnd  THird  FRST  RD
```

and i want to be it like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```py
>>> a = np.random.randint(100, size=(4,4))
>>> a
array([[38, 51, 49,  6],
       [81, 16, 84, 75],
       [76, 83, 13, 92],
       [99, 76,  8, 91]])

>>> a.sum(axis=0)
array([294, 226, 154, 264])
```

---

```
# get the sort indices
>>> idx = np.argsort(a.sum(axis=0))

# copy the array based on the sorted indices
>>> b = np.copy(a[:,idx])

>>> b.sum(axis=0)
array([154, 226, 264, 294])
```